# Uncaught ReferenceError:doPostBack is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, dopostback

I am getting the __doPostBack is not defined and I have tried the fixes, yet it still remains this is using jQuery-ui and jQuery.  My Delete button originally does this.

```
<td><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Home", new {id = testUser.TestUserId})"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg text-primary"></i></a></td>
```

I wanted to add a confirmation screen for when that button was clicked.  The screen does pop up and when I click No it closes.  When I click yes I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError:doPostBack is not defined"
My script doesn't have an input, but I try adding one, but nothing seem to change.
my code is as follows

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/themes/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form id="form1" runat="server" document.forms[0].submit()>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Confirmation",
                width: 350,
                height: 160,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        id: "Yes",
                        text: "Yes",
                        click: function () {
                            $("[id*=btnDelete]").attr("rel", "delete");
                            $("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        id: "No",
                        text: "No",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    _doPostBack(this, '');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteRecord" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>

    <div id="dialog" style="display: none" align="center">
        Do you want to delete this record?
    </div>
</form>
```

the line that seems to be flagged for the error is

```
<div id="dialog1"></div>
```

I believe I have run out of places to look.

Comment: you are using webforms server side code for `OnClick="DeleteRecord"` in `<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteRecord" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>` remove `OnClick="DeleteRecord"` it should work fine as you are making the call from client side

Comment: you are supposed to use `@Url.Action`  or `@HTML.ActionLink` if you are using .NET MVC.

Comment: as per your code you have not defined  `_doPostBack` as mentioned in this else block `else {
                    _doPostBack(this, '');
                }` . Ideally this call is handled by .NET webforms, we are not supposed to call the postback method manually.

Comment: Removing the OnClick did not correct the issue.  Where am I suppose to use @Url.Action or @HTML.ActionLink?  DO I put that in place of the __doPostBack?  I just need it to continue on with the call  href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Home", new {id = testUser.TestUserId})"><i class="fa fa

Comment: this code should work fine if you allready have a DeleteUser method in your Home controller `<td><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Home", new {id = testUser.TestUserId})"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg text-primary"></i></a></td>`

Comment: This doesn't even compile?? $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    __doPostBack("DelBtn", "<td><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Home", new {id = testUser.TestUserId})"><i class="fa fa - trash fa - lg text - primary"></i></a></td>");

                }
            });

Comment: this doesn't compile  $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Home", new {id = testUser.TestUserId})"><i class="fa fa - trash fa - lg text - primary"></i></a></td>;

                }
            });

Comment: If __doPostBack I still get that its not defined...

Comment: Has this question been lost?